# move inline-block div below its siblings

Tags: html, layout, position, css

Without changing HTML layout using only CSS, how can I change the position of div02 so that it stays below all of the other divs? They are all inline-block elements. I'd rather not use floats. On the other hand positioning divs relative/absolute will not push the paragraph down. Is there any other solution to do it in a relatively clean way? Unfortunately I can't touch the HTML.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div01">1</div>
  <div class="div02">2</div>
  <div class="div03">3</div>
  <div class="div04">4</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: auto;   
}

p {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.div01, .div02, .div03, .div04, .div05 {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;    
}

.div02 {
  width: 150px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is you can set `positon:relative` to parent and set `position:absolute` to the `div` which you want to move and set the position accordingly

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position:relative;
}
p {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.div01,
.div02,
.div03,
.div04,
.div05 {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.div02 {
  width: 150px;
}
.div02 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div01">1</div>
  <div class="div02">2</div>
  <div class="div03">3</div>
  <div class="div04">4</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I can do this but my problem is that I need the paragraph to be below the divs - and to be pushed down depending on the divs height

Comment: i dont think it is possible you will need to move the paragraph by changing position